# Eloquent select from database, get results newer than a given unix timestamp

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I would like to select rows from my database newer than some specified UNIX timestamp specified in the parameters.

The column `created_at` is a datetime in the table `tracks`.
The parameter `$timestamp` is a UNIX timestamp (an integer).

So I am trying with
`Tracks::where('created_at','>=',$timestamp)->get();` which simply returns all tracks, no matter which $timestamp I specify.

However I can see the type problem, and I have tried different things like writing 'UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at)' instead of created_at, but with no luck.

So I assume there is some elegant and simple way of doing this. Can you help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 ways to solve this.

1. Use `Tracks::where(DB::raw('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at)'),'>=',$timestamp)`
2. Use a `DateTime` or `Carbon` object.

like this:

```
$timestamp = Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimestamp($timestamp);
Tracks::where('created_at','>=',$timestamp)->get();
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks. Used the Carbon-method.